# Switch ColdFusion 11 from built in web server to IIS

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I originally installed ColdFusion 11 in a local environment (windows 7) and selected "Use built in web server". Everything was working pretty good. Now months later, I realize I need to use a real web server for URL rewrites (Apache, IIS, etc) but there is no documentation I can find on how to do so.

I have attempted looking through the administrator's panel for any information, but couldn't even get a jumping off point. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for ServerFault, but .. a good place to start is with a web search and [the documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/configuring-your-system.html) ;-) A quick search for "Configuring ColdFusion for IIS" returned a ton of blog entries on the subject. There are slight differences by version (CF and IIS), but the general process is similar: 1. Make sure necessary windows features are installed (ISAPI Extensions, etcetera). 2. Run the Web Server Configuration Tool GUI.

Answer (score 1):

First, it sounds like you need to decide which web server you want/need to use and that could be determined by where you'll end up hosting your site. CF code is quite portable but if you're doing URL rewrites, file system access, etc... then you need to code those to match the production environment, otherwise you might find yourself having to rewrite and retest all that again.

As commented above, a lot of information about configuring CF for web servers is available by searching. You'll first need to install & configure your web server, so search around that first. Then you'll need to configure the web server to understand which requests to pass to ColdFusion's engine.

If it's IIS then you need to make sure IIS is installed and the following components are installed: ISAPI Extensions, ISAPI Filters, CGI, ASP .NET

Then configure an IIS site to point to your CF code and after that use the "Web Server Configuration Tool" application (installed with CF) that will associate the relevant file types with ColdFusion.

Most of the time it's as simple as that.